# how to print all HTML Element after using selenium to login (SPA website)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

[image: I tried to print text data from class in an image below but I'm not there yet so here i am asking for somehelp]

i log in by selenium and then wait the page to change html element then using bs4 to find the class.
dont know if it has something to do with single page application

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
chrome_browser.maximize_window()


try:
   chrome_browser.get('https://---something-----/admin')


   username = chrome_browser.find_element_by_id('user')
   username.clear()
   username.send_keys('username')

   password = chrome_browser.find_element_by_id('pass')
   password.clear()
   password.send_keys('password')
   button = chrome_browser.find_element_by_class_name('formButton')
   button.click()
   time.sleep(20)

   html = chrome_browser.page_source
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
   data = soup.find("td", {"class": "formLink"})
   print(data.text)
finally:
   chrome_browser.quit()
```

---

appreciate all the answer

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqszP.png
here is an image

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all `td` using `findAll` method:

```
form_links = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "formLink"})
for link in form_links:
    print(link.text)
```

Better to use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the login instead of `sleep`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...
chrome_browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# ...
chrome_browser.find_element_by_class_name('formButton').click()

form_links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.formLink')))

for link in form_links:
    print(link.text)
```